# Conflicting benchmark tests while looping over nested arrays

Tags: javascript

**Info**

I am trying to create a effective way to loop over an array with nested objects/arrays as the function looping the data will run frequently and filter values based on if they are matching records in another array containing objects.

The data I am working with has the following types.

```js
type WatchedShows = {
    showId: number;
    season: number;
    episode: number;
}[];

type Shows = {
    id: number;
    seasons: {
        season: {
            season_number: number;
            episodes: {
                episode_number: number;
            }[];
        };
    }[];
}[];
```

The data in `WatchedShows` is in my own database so I can control how it is sent to the frontend but, the data in `Shows` comes from an external API.

What I am trying to do is filter all episodes in `Shows` that matches the data in `WatchedShows` and also filter seasons and whole shows if everything is marked as watched.

**Problem**

Currently I have 3 different solutions but, the first was 3 nested loops and became slow quickly with some data so realistically I have 2 solutions. I also need to return the data in the format of `Shows`

I have now tried to run them through a benchmark and tested a bit with timers and checking how many iterations each of them have. Looking at the result from the test I did my self there is a clear winner as one has a run time of `~5ms and 42637 iterations` while the other has a run time of `~15ms and 884052 iterations`.

I then tried to run it through [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/edl3stbtan/1) and when I do that its the opposite solution that comes out as the winner with the website saying its 90% faster. How can that happen when that solution has 884052 iterations and the other 42637 iterations? Is it my solutions that are badly optimized or are there something else I am missing? Tips on improving the solutions would be appreciated.

Both test were done with the same code generated dataset with about 20 000 episode records spread over 26 shows, 20 seasons in each and 40 episodes in each season. The code that generates the dataset can be seen on the benchmark site if needed. The benchmark can be seen [here](https://jsbench.me/edl3stbtan/1)

**Code**

The solution with 884052 iterations and run time of ~15ms looks like this

```js
const newShowObject = {};

for (const show of shows) {
    newShowObject[show.id] = { ...show };
}

for (const show of watchedShows) {
    for (const season of newShowObject[show.showId].seasons) {
        if (season.season_number !== show.season) {
            continue;
        }
        season.episodes = season.episodes.filter(
            (episode) => episode.episode !== show.episode
        );
    }

    newShowObject[show.showId].seasons = newShowObject[show.showId].seasons.filter(
        (season) => season.episodes.length > 0
    );
}

const unwatchedShows = [...Object.values(newShowObject)].filter(
    (show) => show.seasons.length > 0
);
```

The solution with 42637 iterations and run time of ~5ms looks like this

```js
const newShowObject = {};

for (const show of shows) {
    newShowObject[show.id] = { ...show };

    const newSeasons = {};

    for (const seasons of show.seasons) {
        newSeasons[seasons.season_number] = { ...seasons };

        const newEpisodes = {};

        for (const episodes of seasons.episodes) {
            newEpisodes[episodes.episode] = { ...episodes };
        }

        newSeasons[seasons.season_number].episodes = { ...newEpisodes };
    }
    newShowObject[show.id].seasons = { ...newSeasons };
}

for (const show of watchedShows) {
    delete newShowObject[show.showId].seasons[show.season].episodes[show.episode];
}

let unwatchedShows = [...Object.values(newShowObject)];

for (const show of unwatchedShows) {
    show.seasons = [...Object.values(show.seasons)];
    for (const season of show.seasons) {
        season.episodes = [...Object.values(season.episodes)];
    }
    show.seasons = show.seasons.filter((season) => season.episodes.length > 0);
}

unwatchedShows = unwatchedShows.filter((show) => show.seasons.length > 0);
```

Comment: What does "iterations" mean here? The jsbench you linked shows only an "ops/s" value.

Comment: Iterations is a counter I increment in every loop when I am testing. Just adding i++; inside every loop.

Comment: Oh? Can you show that code, please? You might have missed some loops.

Comment: First solution https://pastebin.com/LCfBgj5H
Second solution: https://pastebin.com/jvngeVpf

Comment: Array spread syntax and `Object.values()` are also loops in disguise… but that shouldn't matter here

Comment: Ahh good to know. But It wont make up the difference between the 800k vs 40k iterations. Actually its even worse now after I tried to add a shuffle to the dataset so its not in order 1260064 / 20ms vs 43238 / 7ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your benchmark is flawed. Notice that jsbench does run the "setup code" only once per test case, not for each test loop iteration.

Your first solution does mutate the input (particularly `season.episodes` - while it *does* clone each show), so only on the first run it actually gives the correct output. On all subsequent runs of the test loop, it basically runs on an empty input, which is much faster.

I fixed this [here](https://jsbench.me/tul3sz25vb/1), and now the second solution is the fastest as expected. (Notice the times do now also include creating the object, though).

Comment: Ahh that's it, makes sense. I always had one commented out while I tested locally so it never mutated there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are getting faster results with the second solution, I would triple check results. The JSBench results are legit, and agrees with Big-O notation.

The first solution loops through `shows` to create a look up table. Then, loops through a nested loop with quad complexity O(n^2).

The second solution loops through nested loops with cubic complexity O(n^3), because it is nested thrice. So, I would expect this algorithm to chew up more time.

The reason for this is called the *sum rule*. When two loops sit side-by-side, they don't multiply but add up. This makes the complexity O(n + n^2), which can be further reduced to O(n^2) because the first loop becomes negligible as `n` approaches infinity.

Comment: Notice the first snippet has a `filter` call in two nested loops, so it's `O(n³)` as well

Comment: I have looked at the values and they seem to be correct and also identical given the same dataset. I also tried to add a shuffle to the datasets to see if that had an impact but, the one that the benchmark says is fastest was the one who took the biggest hit by that. So I am not really sure, seems strange though. I get consistently faster times and alot lower iteration numbers with the one the benchmark says is 90% slower.

Comment: @Bergi, not quite, is the `episodes` dataset unbound? If not, it has constant complexity which is negligible.

Comment: @beautifulcoder Yes, it's unbound. See the code in the benchmark, it's creating `totalShows * seasonsPerShow * episodesPerSeason` items.